# Prevent Bruteforcing Without Use of MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, security

I was looking into ways of preventing users from bruteforcing login scripts. I found two good ways:

```
-Use reCaptcha
-Check database before verifying user info to see how 
 many requests the user has made in the last x secs/mins
```

I'd rather not have to use a captcha because they're ugly and I know many users don't like them, and I was thinking the database approach wouldn't be too efficient.

Imagine a user running a bruteforcer and making a ton of requests per second. Wouldn't that be hard on the database server if it has to make a connection -> get # of previous requests -> close connection every second?

I mean, I could always set it up so the user's IP would be blocked from making a connection to my server after x seconds, but would the database approach still be the best way to go?

Does anyone know of a good way to prevent login bruteforces? I run an Ubuntu 13.10 server with latest nginx installed.

Comment: Can you please clarify the situation and your goal as per the discussion in the comments for @krisFR's answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP (and the term "NGINX" from the question makes me think so), then you cam compare the difference (in miliseconds) between the user last action (page view / form submit / ...) and the current timestamp (using $_SESSION)

**Example:**
The code below should be put in the app header (page_top.php or something)

```
session_start();

$threshold = 500; // miliseconds

$_SESSION["current_timestamp"] = microtime(true);

if ($_SESSION["current_timestamp"] - $_SESSION["last_timestamp"] <= $threshold) {
   // 500 miliseconds didn't pass since the user last action
   die('Slow down ...');
}
else {
   // update the last timestamp with the current one
   $_SESSION["last_timestamp"] = $_SESSION["current_timestamp"]; 
}
```